# Suggestion for tag synonyms [self-host] vs [self-hosting]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I just looked up this term on Stack Overflow to learn up, and in the process I found the questions are split between two similar tags that probably ought to be synonyms, but since I've never used either tag I don't have the "score" necessary to suggest them as synonyms.

So I'm bringing them to the attention of the community should they wish to merge them:

- [self-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-host) - 48 questions
- [self-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting) - 310 questions

Comment: Both these tags should be destroyed.

Comment: I leave it in the hands of whoever makes such decisions, which hands are not my own ...

Comment: And I'll sit over here and hand-wring!

Comment: That seems to be a pretty strange definition of [tag:self-hosting] anyway. To me, self-hosting means a tool that can make a newer version of itself. E.g., `make` being used to build a newer version of `make`, GCC being used to compile a newer version of GCC, Eclipse being used to develop a newer version of Eclipse, etc.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It depends on the context.  Services that were traditionally hosted inside another service, such as websites being hosted in apache, now have options for self-hosting where they operate independently as both the HTTP host and the website.  It's becoming more common for certain niche applications, so **I wouldn't call it strange, but certainly without any context it is ambiguous** for the reasons you point out.

Answer (score 6):

**I think we should burninate these tags as they are too ambiguous.**

- There is no tag wiki for [self-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-host), there are only a few questions, and would be *really broad* to cover the current questions in that tag.
- The tag except for [self-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting) is very broad, but the tag wiki gives it a strangely narrow scope. Unfortunately, it also has the same issue as [self-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-host) where if the tag wiki was accurate to the questions, it would be *incredibly broad*.

It's a sign that the tags are too ambiguous, lets fix this before it turns into [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet).

---

From Wikipedia, "Self-hosting"

> The term self-hosting was coined to refer to the use of a computer program as part of the toolchain or operating system that produces new versions of that same program—for example, a compiler that can compile its own source code. Self-hosting software is commonplace on personal computers and larger systems.

The tag [self-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting) appears to have taken that definition and applied it to only .NET applications and a few cases of people looking to host their own web applications. Part of this might be because of the tag wiki, **which is pretty specific to WCF applications**

> Self-hosting refers to a program or service which does not require a hosting environment. This term is often used to describe WCF web services that do not require IIS as their web host - a self-hosted WCF service establishes its own HTTP endpoints and listeners and is responsible for its own routing, security, and configuration management.

But we've also learned that people usually read those *after* they tag their question, so it is interesting WCF/ASP.NET questions have gravitated towards that tag. After filtering out all WCF/.NET questions, there appeared to be 50 "general purpose" self-hosting questions under the tag.

So, just to recap:

- The tags are ambiguous.
- The tag wikis don't match the excepts (when they exist).
- The tags would be *too broad* if everything was correct.

**Let's burninate them instead.**

Comment: Well it's a year and a bit later and both tags are back: [tag:self-host] has 65 questions and no tag wiki. [tag:self-hosting] has 435 questions and the tag wiki excerpt "Operating independently of a hosting infrastructure"

Comment: I synonymized the two tags, @hippietrail, easier to burn one tag instead.