# Burninate [self-hosting]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

This is a follow-up from the synonym request [Suggestion for tag synonyms [self-host] vs [self-hosting]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285111/1839439).

The tag [self-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting) has 745 questions at the time of writing this proposal.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

I don't think it describes the contents. It describes circumstances.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No. Hosting-related questions are off-topic here.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Well, no, because it's off-topic. So the meaningful information from the tag is that the question using it should probably be closed and deleted. For questions about programming, it doesn't add any meaningful information.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Definitely not.

Comment: Un-host `[self-hosting]`?

Comment: The party is over for `[self-hosting]`?

Comment: Eviction for [self-hosting] (riffing on Nick's first suggestion)

Comment: My first thought was 'self-hosting language compiler' but that's not what the tag wiki is about. Kill it with fire.

Comment: No longer `[self-hosting]`?

Comment: Get over your `[self-hosting]`!

Answer (score 8):

I'm **against** burninating this tag, and here's why. Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73765632/github-self-hosted-actions-runner-service-failing-with-status-133-rh-linux) for reference, so you can verify my answers to tag burnination quiz by an actual example.

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Definitely yes: the question is about self-hosted CI action runner, and the tag adds some context to the question (at least I'm reading this as "if I use self-hosted runner, everything dies").

#### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, CI & CD systems are on-topic, according to point 7 of [SO guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions on *professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

I'm sure that CI actions runner *directly involves programming tools*. Also, present exception traceback, IMO, is a good marker of on-topic, programming-related question.

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes, the fact that runner is self-hosted may be important here.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Almost: it refers to some system running on self-hosted server. It may be related to CI or deployment, but in general this context may be useful and important. It may be considered "too wide", but I don't think [deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deployment) is more focused, for example.

Also, it's important to note that errors really may appear on self-hosted servers, but be absent on cloud service. I have my own case where subtle library version mismatch on Amazon EC2 and my local PC put down the whole application.

One more (perhaps, important) point: if [self-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting) does not fit SO requirements, then shouldn't the same relate to [cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud) with 5-10 new questions daily? **These two tags are two opposite scenarios, applicable in very similar contexts.** Or take [web-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting) tag - it's even closer, has the same format, 3k questions and daily activity!

Also, I know nothing about asp.net and windows-based systems, but it looks like self-hosting asp.net applications is somewhat challenging compared to cloud-based solutions. At least, [ordering questions tagged [self-hosted] by score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting?tab=Votes) shows that most questions in top are asking about asp.net self-hosted apps. I don't really understand these questions, so it would be create to hear from asp.net expert here to know whether the tag is properly used on them.

Comment: To how many question in the tag does this apply to?

Comment: Even asp.net + self-hosted has [54 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting+asp.net). At least ten more ask about self-hosted CI runners - no common tag, though, but [gitlab] gives 5 valid questions, plus [github-actions] one, plus some more (1-2 q per tag each). Also 15 [docker] questions, at least 5 of them are on-topic and meaningfully refer to the fact of self-hosting. And it is just a raw estimate from quick looking through, self-hosting may be important for other questions too.

Comment: Also, I agree that [cloud] should also be removed.

Comment: Can confirm that there is a difference between cloud hosting an ASP.NET app and self-hosting it.

Comment: @Bellrampion I can confirm there is a difference between cloud hosting an ASP.NET app and self-hosting it. For one thing, the availability of certain configuration options is different.